# hapi-fhir-android library : how to bypass getting conformance?

Tags: android, hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

I'm trying to access FHIR resources from a FHIR server. Everything works fine when accessing the FHIR resources via postman

This is my code:

```
String serverBase = https://<fhir-server-url>;

//Adding required headers here - removed as irrelevant for this question

IGenericClient client = ctx.newRestfulGenericClient(serverBase);
client.setEncoding(EncodingEnum.JSON);

Patient p = client.read(Patient.class, "jasdkfljasdklfjasldfkja");
String resPatient = p.getName().get(0).getGiven().toString();
```

**PROBLEM:** The conformance functionality is broken and I am not being able to proceed with doing any operations on resources because the `IGenericClient` gets the conformance when initiating by calling `https://<fhir-server-url>/metadata`.

It is going to take time for the conformance functionality to get fixed. Meanwhile, I was wondering if there is a way to bypass getting the conformance by setting a flag or something so that i can access the FHIR resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out myself. Can be done as follows:

```
FhirContext fhirfctx = FhirContext.forDstu2();

// bypass conformance check  

fhirfctx.getRestfulClientFactory().setServerValidationMode(ServerValidationModeEnum.NEVER);
```